# Como desabilitar X do JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Como desabilitar o X de um frame?

A opção abaixo que encontrei apenas não executa a ação de fechar:

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

Preciso que o botão X do frame fique desabilitado e não permita clicar.

Comment: Você precisa tirar o botão?

Comment: Sim, mas sem tirar o contorno do frame onde fica escrito o título se possível

Comment: Quero q ele não apareça

Comment: Não é possivel remover apenas o botao, porque não é o java que o define,  e sim seu sistema operacional. Para remove-lo, você precisaria construir a decoração do Frame do zero. O mais próximo disso seria chamar `setUndecorated(true);` e desativar a decoração, porém sua janela não terá mais a borda superior, q exibe o titulo e os outros botoes de minimizar e maximizar. Referencia:[How to disable (or hide) the close (x) button on a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276254/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-close-x-button-on-a-jframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível remover apenas o botão, porque é a decoração quem define aqueles botões, em sincronia com seu sistema operacional.

Para remove-lo, você precisaria construir a decoração do Frame do zero ou encontrar alguma que permita esse tipo de edição.

A forma menos complicada de fazer isso seria chamar `setUndecorated(true);` e desativar a decoração, porém sua janela não terá mais a borda superior, a que  exibe o titulo e os outros botões de minimizar e maximizar.

Referencias:

[How to disable (or hide) the close (x) button on a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276254/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-close-x-button-on-a-jframe)

[How to hide the default minimize/maximize and close buttons on JFrame window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9101418/5524514)